# Swift: Thread safety of weak properties

Tags: swift, thread-safety

I am writing a code, similar in logic to this:

```
enum FooState {
    case open
    case closed
}

protocol FooDelegate: AnyObject {
    func foo(_ foo: Foo, didChange state: FooState)
}

class Foo: NSObject {
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.test.fooQueue")
    private(set) var state: FooState? {
        didSet {
            guard let state = state else {
                return
            }

            delegate?.foo(self, didChange: state)
        }
    }
    weak var delegate: FooDelegate?

    func close() {
        // Do some extra logic here...
        didChangeFooState(.closed)
    }

    private func didChangeFooState(_ state: FooState) {
        queue.async { [weak self] in
            self?.state = state
        }
    }
}
```

Then, elsewhere in the app (on main queue), at some point, I call:

```
foo.close()
foo = nil
```

Now, this works most of the time, but in very rare cases, I can get a crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` on line `delegate?.foo(self, didChange: state)`.

So the question, what is going on here?

My guess is that there is a race-condition that occurs since state property is assigned on com.test.fooQueue, but foo is being deinitialized on main queue. Can someone confirm if I'm on the right track here, or if something else is going on?

Although, I was under the impression that reference counting was atomic.

Would it make a difference if I `guard let delegate` instead of optionally unwrap it?

Comment: Look into actors it might be a viable alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `didSet` is invalid. It reads `state` on whatever queue it is called on. `state` is also set on the com.test.fooQueue queue. If you have a queue that modifies a property, then that is also the only queue that can read the property, or you must use locks. Your `didSet` logic needs to move to the correct queue.

Note that `state` also needs to be private, or you need to make it computed, in order to fetch the data on the right queue. It is always invalid to read and write properties simultaneously on different threads.

Actors make it a lot simpler to implement correct patterns, so if possible, you should use that. But if you can't use actors, you have to do all the queue management yourself.

Comment: I appreciate your thorough reply! Your observations regarding updating state from different queues are correct.
However, in this case, the BAD_ACCESS crash is on the line where delegate is called, at which point, as you can see, state is already in local scope, which leads me to believe that it is the de-referencing of delegate that is the root issue. Do you have any insights regarding that?

Comment: "In local scope" isn't meaningful here. During optimization, the compiler made assumptions about what it was allowed to do based on defined behavior. When you created undefined behavior (allowing multiple threads to modify memory), you broke those assumptions. Your theory about deinit on the wrong queue is not correct here. In Swift, access to properties is explicitly protected against unexpected deinit. (There are historical exceptions, specifically if you use KVO which is unfortunately not thread-safe, where your theory could be correct, but not here.)

Comment: If you did find a case where deinit was being called on another thread while you were accessing a property, then that would be very likely be a compiler bug (it does happen sometimes). But I would not suspect a compiler bug here when your own bug is so obvious.